# How does Azure Dead-Lettered Message count work in Service Bus Standard Metrics?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, dead-letter

I configured azure metric alert when there is a dead-lettered message in a specific topic.

The dead-lettered queue only has one message but I discovered that when using Average, it is not always remain as absolute number (1) sometime it shows as 0.8 or 1.2
[image]

And when I used Maximum, it shows as 2 messages in the dead-lettered queue (sometime fluctuate to 1).
[image]

Any idea how does Azure actually calculate the dead-lettered queue metrics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior for average as it is calculated for a time period.

Calculating by segment might provide accurate results.

[image]